# Debugging weird program termination

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I have a project that has a pile of code in it, and to my understanding this pile of code starts influencing app stability up to a point where I'm unable to debug it. The app consists of several executables such as ui and couple of daemons handling different actions under different user spaces. One of those daemons has started to behave oddly by exiting with non-zero return value via execution of code below (in XCode 9.1 Beta) while the code works perfectly fine in XCode 8.

```
import Foundation

dispatchMain();
```

I was trying to put breakpoints on every possible exception XCode could debug. I was going down to putting breakpoints at instruction level in `exit` function, it's not being called.

I can't figure out how in a world such thing can even happen or how to debug such a case. Any thoughts in this regard are appreciated!

Comment: have you tried running the stable-(stabler) version XCode 9.0?

Comment: Yes, the same behavior for version XCode 9.0